# BB Simulator does not start

Tags: blackberry-simulator

When I run my BB Simulator; I keep getting the following error:

### Port in Use - BlackBerry Smartphone Simulator

Could not open port 19780 because it is in use by another program (possibly another instance of this simulator). You must close the other program for network operations to function correctly.

I have modified rimpublic.properties under MDS/config, but no luck.
[UDP]
UDP.receive.port=29781
UDP.send.default=29780

Any suggestions to get MDS and Simulator running???
I am running Win 7.

Comment: You can use `netstat -a -b |find "19780"` in an elevated privilege command prompt to see what process is bound to that port.

Comment: Already tried that... no process listed. C:\Users\Nirmal>netstat -a -b | find "19780"
C:\Users\Nirmal>

Comment: Restarting my desktop does not fix this. If the port was being bound to a process; I would assume it to be freed up when machine is booted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had Microsoft Client for ISA Server installed on my machine and that seems to be causing problems for BB MDS simulator. MDS and BB Simulator work fine after disabling the ISA client.

In general if the MDS simulator is having problems running, there is a another web server running on the machine which is causing port conflicts.